# Cyrillic in the file name when upload to ftp C #

Tags: c#, file-upload, encoding, ftpwebrequest, cyrillic

I am writing a program that uploads a file to remote ftp server. However, downloaded files sometimes contain Cyrillic. The contents of the file load correctly, but the name is distorted. I understand that this is due to the encoding.
I tried to use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(file.FileName))`
and other encodings. Does not help. At the same time, the php script that is stored on the same ftp correctly uploads files with cyrillic letters.

```
public void FtpUpload(IFormFile file, string filePath)
{
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/" + filePath);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
        byte[] fileBytes;
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(ms);
                fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        else return;

        request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
        using (Stream request_stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            request_stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            request_stream.Close();
        }
}
```

`filePath = "Тест.pdf"`

I tried to use  `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filePath)`. Nothing helps. Tell me, please, how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. After scrolling through a few more forums, I came across the following solution:

Through `NuGet Package Management` install the package `System.Net.FtpClient`.
Then we write the following code:

```
public void FtpClientUpload(IFormFile file, string filePath)
    {
        FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient();
        ftp.Host = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx";
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
        ftp.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

        using (var remote = ftp.OpenWrite( filePath, FtpDataType.Binary))
            file.CopyTo(remote);
    }
```